# How to remove everything from tweet but plain text with php?

Tags: php, regex, twitter, plaintext, tweets

I'm trying to get rid of urls, mentions, hashtags from a tweet to get only the actual text so instead of:

`Hello this is a test @someone #tag1 #tag2 http://bit.ly/123`

it'd be just:

`Hello this is a test`

I believe I'd have to use some sort of regular expression but I'm terrible at it, could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to do it in three regular expressions (you could probably merge all three in one, but let's not go there!)

```
$str = preg_replace('/(^|\b)@\S*($|\b)/', '', $str); // remove @someone
$str = preg_replace('/(^|\b)#\S*($|\b)/', '', $str); // remove hashtags

// taken from http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
$urlRegex = '~(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))~';
$str = preg_replace($urlRegex, '', $str); // remove urls
```

Answer (score 4):

A preg_replace() will do the work

```
$str = "Hello this is a test @someone #tag1 #tag2 http://bit.ly/123";
$str = preg_replace('/#([\w-]+)/i', '', $str); // @someone
$str = preg_replace('/@([\w-]+)/i', '', $str); // #tag
$str = preg_replace('/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/', '', $str);
```